# Can token liquidity be tracked?

Tags: tokens

I'm working on a personal project which tracks data of BTC token pairs. I'd like to do the same with BNB and liquidity tokens but I'm very ignorant about this subject. I'd like to know what's a specific token liquidity so I'm able to track that data. Is there any source I can find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can track the liquidity of pairs on Binance Smart Chain(bsc) dexs. Since many of the bsc dexs like pancakeswap have very similar contracts as uniswap on ethereum you can follow along with the tutorial linked below to get a really good understanding of how pairs work in uniswap/pancakeswap contracts.

https://vomtom.at/how-to-use-uniswap-v2-as-a-developer/

The simplest way to get this all started is to use metamask, web3, geth or infura and some kind of IDE like Atom. You will have to change some settings on metamask to connect to BSC.The only real difference between tracking liquidity with uniswap versus many dexs on BSC are the addresses.

If you are able to understand the tutorial you will have enough knowledge to understand how you would track liquidity of BSC Pancake token pairs or Ethereum uniswap token pairs. By the way both have their own version of BNB tokens.

https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/how-to-get-started-with-binance-smart-chain-bsc

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/getting-started.html

https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html

Comment: Thanks for the response Julian. I'm already using web3.py and I'm somewhat familiar with how to deploy smart contracts. Thank you for your response, I'll be reading the article once I get home, I'm assuming the calculation I've to do in order to get liquidity uses some of BNB, X (token) & Pancakeswap data? Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Thank you for your response, I learned so much from the article!

Comment: Useless downvote.

Comment: This answer does answer how to track liquidity. It just describes how to query data from blockchain. A helpful answer would provide examples of contracts that describe LP pairs, show how to query, how to get ratio in the pool, and how to determine value of each pool in ETH.

Comment: I am happy to contribute an answer too. Just stumbled upon this while looking for additional validation about polling liquidity.

Comment: Shared my insights https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/99322/70785

Comment: Question does not ask HOW liquidity can be tracked. It ask, CAN liquidity be tracked. I answered that liquidity or anything else related to the token can be tracked by querying data from a blockchain. My answer was helpful to the asker. Either way, thanks for the welcoming downvote.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer, since the final result does not match what I expect it to be, but the basic logic is as follows:

Let's use this contract as an example:

[`0x2A9718defF471f3Bb91FA0ECEAB14154F150a385`](https://bscscan.com/address/0x2A9718defF471f3Bb91FA0ECEAB14154F150a385)

At the time of writing, BoggedFinance says that the liquidity of the token is $14,125,954. And the accompanying note states:

> Liquidity includes both ElonGate and BNB value from LP total

As I type this, I discovered that BoggedFinance provides a detail breakdown of LP:

> ElonGate - BNB LP PancakeSwap V1
> One LP is worth $556.758
> 1,498,788,818.175 ElonGate + 0.890 BNB
>
> Liquidity Pool Totals
> Pool adds $10,509,932.851 to total liquidity
>
> ElonGate pooled: 28,292,667,705,973.550
>
> BNB pooled: 16,803.212
>
> Total LP Tokens: 18,877.021
>
> ElonGate - BUSD LP PancakeSwap V1
> One LP is worth $52.411
> 140,320,177.619 ElonGate + 26.206 BUSD
>
> Liquidity Pool Totals
> Pool adds $88.507 to total liquidity
>
> ElonGate pooled: 236,957,969.712
>
> BUSD pooled: 44.253
>
> Total LP Tokens: 1.689
>
> ElonGate - BNB LP PancakeSwap V2
> One LP is worth $4,711.863
> 12,878,292,502.135 ElonGate + 7.533 BNB
>
> Liquidity Pool Totals
> Pool adds $3,684,693.138 to total liquidity
>
> ElonGate pooled: 10,070,868,300,296.424
>
> BNB pooled: 5,891.063
>
> Total LP Tokens: 782.003
>
> ElonGate - BUSD LP PancakeSwap V2
> One LP is worth $43.974
> 94,155,951.896 ElonGate + 21.987 BUSD
>
> Liquidity Pool Totals
> Pool adds $15.409 to total liquidity
>
> ElonGate pooled: 32,993,962.665
>
> BUSD pooled: 7.705
>
> Total LP Tokens: 0.350

This helpful.

Let's break this down, starting with PancakeSwap V1:

> ElonGate - BNB LP PancakeSwap V1
> One LP is worth $556.758
> 1,498,788,818.175 ElonGate + 0.890 BNB
>
> Liquidity Pool Totals
> Pool adds $10,509,932.851 to total liquidity
>
> ElonGate pooled: 28,292,667,705,973.550
>
> BNB pooled: 16,803.212
>
> Total LP Tokens: 18,877.021

This says that LP is added from PancakeSwap pair that holds ElongGate/BNB.

As far as I understand, the way to find the pair is:

1. find individual contract addresses (ElongGate, [WBNB](https://bscscan.com/token/0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c))
2. calculate pair address

How does one do #2? Uniswap documentation describes a [method using hash of two contract addresses](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contract-integration/getting-pair-addresses/). However, it is not clear how that works now that we have v1 and v2 pairs.

In this case, I figured out addresses by analyzing transactions using BoggedTools.

- [`0x4C82B6CE77Ee16EbaeB5e37098F18d1E722e1601`](https://bscscan.com/token/0x4C82B6CE77Ee16EbaeB5e37098F18d1E722e1601) v1
- [`0x7f1bb2D98aD5ba6Fae2a86acfc170cC2edfd57ec`](https://bscscan.com/token/0x7f1bb2D98aD5ba6Fae2a86acfc170cC2edfd57ec) v2

We are interested in v1, so let's stick with that.

I think we should be looking at the [`getReserves`](https://bscscan.com/token/0x4C82B6CE77Ee16EbaeB5e37098F18d1E722e1601#readContract) values. In this case these are:

```
 _reserve0 uint112, _reserve1 uint112, _blockTimestampLast uint32
  _reserve0|uint112 :  28275429447945283354076
  _reserve1|uint112 :  16813513482151690059189
  _blockTimestampLast|uint32 :  1621474820
```

As far as I understand, these values represent how much liquidity has been added to the contract. In this case, `_reserve0` represents ElonGate and `_reserve1` represents WBNB. The ratio of these values represents tokens price, i.e.

```
(28275429447945283354076/10^9) / (16813513482151690059189/10^18)
= 1,681,708,554.13182609680802084772
```

A quick check back with BoggedTools confirms this:

ElonGate/BNB: 1681713503.587

The reserve in this case also represents liquidity, i.e. it says that this pool consists of:

- WBNB 16,814 (16813513482151690059189/10^18) (16,814 * 427.17 = USD ~7.4M)
- ElonGate 28T (28T*0.000000195156 = 5,518,119.70934320971824805586 = USD ~5.5)

The total therefore should be USD 12.9. This number does not entirely align with what BoggedFinance suggests though:

> Pool adds $10,509,932.851 to total liquidity.

There is some logic problem in this, and I suspect it is in the last step. However, this should give a head start to whoever is just starting to analyze how DEX function.

Comment: can you share the get reserves abi and full code.

Answer (score -1):

[Trading Strategy protocol](https://tradingstrategy.ai/) (disclaimer: I'm affiliated with this site) provides [historical APIs](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/backtesting) and [real time APIs](https://tradingstrategy.ai/api/explorer/) for tracking liquidity.
Binance Smart Chain will be added soon.

[See documentation on liquidity tracking](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/programming/api/liquidity.html).